# Read txt file into HTML table

Tags: html

I have to read a txt file into a HTML table.
There are many fields in it but I only want to read the field that says "value".

Here is my txt file:

```
one=availability:, timestamp=90754, value=no
two=description:, timestamp=074693, value=not sure
three=Name, timestamp=90761, value=yes
```

The one, two, three values are my row headers and I want it to display the values underneath.

Is there anyway of doing this using iframe?? PHP is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the value is always the last field and you are reading the file line by line I would use a dirty approach:

```
$value = explode('value=', $line)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If all rows follow the same pattern you can probably use:

```
//$textfilestring = "one=availability:, timestamp=90754, value=no
               //two=description:, timestamp=074693, value=not sure
               //three=Name, timestamp=90761, value=yes";
$textfilestring = file_get_contents("PATH_TO_FILE");
$arraylines = explode("\n", $textfilestring);

for ($i=0;$i<count($arraylines);$i++) {
    $arraylines[$i] = explode("value=", $arraylines[$i]);

}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arraylines);
echo "</pre>";

echo $arraylines[0][1] . "<br>";
echo $arraylines[1][1] . "<br>";
echo $arraylines[2][1] . "<br>";
```

$arraylines should be twodimensional with one part beeing

```
one=availability:, timestamp=90754,
```

and one beeing

```
no
```

Not tested though.

Comment: how do you make arrayline two deimensiona? Can you provide me with a good tutorial website?

Comment: @doctorwho11 Sorry there was a few errors in the code. They are now fixed.

Comment: $textfilestring = file_get_contents("PATH_TO_FILE");

Comment: I'm still confused about how to display one value in a table (or why, you usually have more than one value in a table). Is timestamp supposed to be value2?

Answer (score 0):

longwinded approach

```
$headers=[];
$values=[];
$lines = file('./homework.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $chunks = explode(',',$line);
        foreach($chunks as $index => $chunk){
            list($key, $value) = explode('=', trim($chunk));
            if(!$index){
                $headers[] = $value;
            }
            if('value' === $key){
                $values[] = $value;
            }
        }
}

echo "<table><thead><tr>";
foreach($headers as $h){    
    echo "<th>{$h}</th>";   
}
echo "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
foreach($values as $v){
    echo "<td>{$v}</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```